# How to remove certain lines when reading FASTA files?

Tags: c++, bioinformatics

I'm trying to read in the database down below into a vector of strings while removing the header lines (lines with >db) and imputing each sequence below it into a string.

This is the code I have right now:

```
void read_in_database_file(string db_file) {
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(db_file);
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {//if
            cerr << "Error did not open file" << endl;
            exit(1);
    }//if

    vector<string> database;
    string line = "";

    while(getline(fin, line, '>'))
    {
            database.push_back(line);
    }

    finding_kmers(database);
}

int main() {
    cout << "\n" << endl;
    cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------ BLAST -----------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Welcome to BLAST" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the name of your datafile" << endl;
    string db_file = "";
    getline(cin, db_file);

    cout << endl;

    read_in_database_file(db_file);
}
```

Currently, all it does is simply remove the ">" but print that line and everything else as is. How do i solve this?

database file:

```
>db_1
GATCTTGCATTTAGAAAATCATAAGAAATTTACTAAAAAGTATTAGGACTCATGAACAAATTTAAGAATG
TAACACTATATAAGATTGGTATACAAAAATAACTGTACTTCTTCACCAAGAAATCAAGAATCCAAAAATG
>db_2
TAGTTTGTTCTAGGATTTATGTGTTTCCTTAAAGTCTTAGTTTGATTATGTTACATTTAGCATGAGTGAC
TCCATTTTGGTTTGGTTTGGTCTGTTGGGACCTATTGCATGAGTTTAGTTCAAAACAATGGCCTCCCATA
>db_3
TTGTCCTTGCGATAGTTTACTGAGAATGATGATTTCCAATTTCATCCATATCCCTACAAAGGACATGAAC
TCATCATTTTTTATGGCTGCATAGTATTCCATGGTGTATATGTGCCATAATTTCTCAATCCAGTCTATCG
```

Comment: Your code does not skip any line at all. Skipping a line supposes to use the conditional `database.push_back(line)`. Think about a suitable condition.

Comment: insert `if(!line.empty() && line[0]=='>') continue; ` in the while loop, before `database.push_back(line);`

Comment: @XinCheng Why have you deleted your answer? After all the effort spent! The last version was good, you even had an upvote!

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica You are the hero I wish to be, kind and strong, thank you so much for helping me out. I just want to simplify it, as the answer is easy, I left the solution in the comment area.

Comment: @XinCheng It's still an answer, and it should be posted as such. If you want to keep it short and simple, which in my opinion is a good idea, you can post it as in your comment.